# Firebase authentication with angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

authentication by Google working fine like by username and password but when Login by google occurred header functionality works slowly and Login by Username and Password works fine? What's the reason for that?

```
signInByEmail(email,password) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(
                (success)=> {                 
                    this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
                    .then(token => {
                        let params = new URLSearchParams();
                        params.set('tsid', `Bearer ${token}`);
                        this.auth.setToken(token);
                    });                 
                    localStorage.setItem('emailUser', email);
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
                }
            ).catch(
                (err)=> {
                    this.showAlert();
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
     }

     signInByGoogle(){
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(
                (success)=> {
                    this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
                    .then(token => {
                        let params = new URLSearchParams();
                        params.set('tsid', `Bearer ${token}`);
                        this.auth.setToken(token);
                    });
                    localStorage.setItem('emailUser', JSON.stringify(success.user.email));
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
                }
            ).catch(
                (err)=> {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
     }
```

There are HostBending in app-root

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostBinding('class.layout-fixed') get isFixed() { return this.settings.layout.isFixed; };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Answer for this issue 
Buttons of Login by Social Links must be inside  tag